# Aonde esta pergunta é erro de digitação?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, fechamento, razões-fechamento

Ando participando da fila de analises novamente e me deparei com isto:

> https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/close/132049

[image: votos]

Eu não vou debater aqui se acho que a pergunta deve ser fechada ou não, o problema é entender aonde exatamente esta o "erro de digitação", pra mim me parece uma pergunta sobre um serviço.

Não estou querendo apontar erros de ninguém, é que eu só quero ter certeza se esse fechamento é apropriado.

Comment: Eu acho que deveria dividir em duas opções, está opção de fechamento, talvez ficaria melhor.

Comment: @gato eu nem estava questionando o motivo correto em si, mas sim a escolha especifica feita por 3 usuários. Eu pessoalmente não consigo ver código algum que tenha erro de digitação ou algo na pergunta que fale de algum script ou ferramenta que não pode ser executada, penso que a pergunta é uma duvida sobre característica e não sobre execução. Creio eu que foi engano deles, mas fiquei na duvida e queria entender o motivo, sem julgar ninguem, afinal todos temos direito de errar :)

Comment: Entendo. Em relação ao fechamento da pergunta, eu acho que fora de escopo não é, portanto que eu nem martelei. A dúvida é sobre uma plataforma especifica, e se esta documentado o limite de armazenamento  de dados eu não sei ;) É bem dificil dizer que é erro de digitação também!

Comment: Pois é, justamente a minha duvida xD

Answer (score 3):

Hipótese apenas: acho que por uma questão de interpretação, alguém deve ter achado que o autor da pergunta teve um problema de estouro de limite/cota de armazenamento ao invés de ter feito apenas uma pergunta aberta. E marcou essa opção de fechamento não pela expressão à direita do **ou** (erro de digitação), mas sim pela expressão à esquerda (problema que não pode ser reproduzido).

Pode ter ocorrido também voto influenciado por voto anterior.

Concordo que a pergunta deve ser fechada por estar fora de escopo, mas acho que devemos atentar a fechar pelo motivo de fuga de escopo correto. Até porque fica confuso para o autor retrucar um motivo de fechamento assim, no caso de perguntas resgatáveis.

Comment: Pode ter sido mesmo influencia, concordo que o fechamento adequado ajuda a evitar desentendimentos e/ou discussões e até causar algum tipo de "mal estar". Vamos aguardar. Obrigado.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento o Renan, já explicou por completo com a hipótese apresentada. Eu escolhi esse fechamento pela parte relacionado ao «Esse problema **não pode ser reproduzido**». Mas pensando melhor, acho que seria o caso de que não estava suficientemente clara para darmos uma resposta de qualidade, se primeiramente, fosse dentro do escopo do site.